# How to check H2 tag with a date against 1 week in the future on a simple web page

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Let's say I have the following HTML page;

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 id='invoiceDueDate'>17/08/2018</h2>
    <h2 id='paymentStatus'>Yet To pay</h2> 
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to check the h2 for the due date, check the payment status for whever its paid or not and if the current day is one week past the invoiceDueDate and is still unpaid then the page needs to display `Payment Over Due`

It may be obvious but if it is paid then do nothing.

It doesn't necessarily have to use moment.js but it has to use this date format: dd/mm/yyyy

Here is the javascript I have used to try to get it working:

```
let dueDate = document.getElementById('invoiceDueDate').innerHTML;
console.log(dueDate)
// this get the the due date from the html and I have used console.log to confirm it works 

let invoiceStatus = document.getElementById('paymentStatus').innerHTML;
console.log(invoiceStatus)
// this get the theinvoiceStatus from the html and it works

const overDue = moment().add(7, 'days').format('L');
console.log(overDue)
// get the current date and adds 7 days and it works
// todays date isnt the due date so adding 7 on to it doesn't work

if(invoiceStatus.innerHTML === 'Yet To pay'){
   if(dueDate >= overDue){
    invoiceStatus.innerHTML = "Overdue";
    console.log('overdue');
  }else{
    invoiceStatus.innerHTML = "Un-paid";
    console.log('not yet paid');
  }
} else {
 // do nothing
}
 // compares the dueDate to overDue then print it out to the page
```

The problem with this javascript is it checks the current date then adds 7 days then print the result rather than adding 7 days to the due day THEN printing the result. This is the problem I'm struggling with.

I hope this makes sense.

Edit:

Also is there anyway to do soemthing like this

```
if(dueDate >= (dueDate + 7 days)){ 
 invoiceStatus.innerHTML = "Overdue";
}
```

I've made changes and added it to codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZaLvb?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your logic is requiring these to be completely identical.  You might want to check instead to see if overdue >= dueDate -- otherwise, it will only count things that are *precisely* overdue, and not n days overdue.

Also, at some points you're trying to hit the innerHTML of an item's innerHTML.

The changes I would make here:

1)  Change:

```
let invoiceStatus = document.getElementById('paymentStatus').innerHTML;
console.log(invoiceStatus);
```

To:

```
let invoiceStatus = document.getElementById('paymentStatus');
console.log(invoiceStatus.innerHTML);
```

2)  Change:

```
if(dueDate === overDue){
```

To:

```
if(overDue >= dueDate){
```

Comment: @Connor I've added a few more specific suggestions.  This looks like it should work to fix your issue.

Comment: Thankyou!, I've updated my code and added it to code pen so all the changes can be viewed without having to edit the post anymore then I have.

Comment: @Connor I think if you edit the innerHTML (item #1), then your code should work.  You may have to also change the date format, though.

Comment: I made the changes and updated it in the code but it's still not working is there any way to do something like this `if(dueDate >= (dueDate + 7 days)){              invoiceStatus.innerHTML = "Overdue"; }`

Comment: What is happening for it right now? Is it changing the text at all?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no matter what I change the date to the text doesn't change. Heres the code pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZaLvb?editors=1010